# How can I slide a div right, giving it the appearance of sliding out from behind a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have a div, it has several links in it. Now I want all these links to make the same div slide from the left side to the right. From the research I've done it looks like I should be using Jquery's animate function. Problem is I haven't seen any examples that do what I want. These are the links in a div.

```css
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
.select {
  font-size: 175%;
  background-color: clear;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.catselect {
  text-decoration: none
}
#categories {
  font-weight: 800;
  position: absolute;
  top: .25%;
  left: 2%;
}
#myHeader1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 3%;
}
#myHeader2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 3%;
}
#myHeader3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16%;
  left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <h1 id="categories">Categories</h1>
  <div class="select">
    <a id="myHeader1" class="catselect" href="#">Comedy</a>
  </div>

  <div class="select">
    <a id="myHeader2" class="catselect" href="#">Horror</a>
  </div>

  <div class="select">
    <a id="myHeader3" class="catselect" href="#">Action</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I want a separate div to slide to the right of the div the links are in and I  want this action to be triggered by the links being clicked.

Comment: "* I want all these links to make the same div slide from the left side to the right*" on hover. click, page load?

Comment: Also you have set `width:100%` to the `#holder` div that's giving it a 100% width of the screen how would it slides? add this `background-color:yellow;` to your `#holder` css and see

Comment: oops that was suppose to be 50%. On click sorry for not being more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but if you mean it slides in from the left you can use CSS to achieve this on hover like this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bo7wxm31/3/)

```css
#holder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  left: -170px;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s;
  transition: left 1s;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#holder:hover {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s;
  transition: left 1s
}
.select {
  font-size: 175%;
  background-color: clear;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.catselect {
  text-decoration: none
}
#categories {
  font-weight: 800;
  top: .25%;
  left: 2%;
}
#myHeader1 {
  top: 7%;
  left: 3%;
}
#myHeader2 {
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 3%;
}
#myHeader3 {
  top: 16%;
  left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <h1 id="categories">Categories</h1>

  <div class="select"> <a id="myHeader1" class="catselect" href="#">Comedy</a>

  </div>
  <div class="select"> <a id="myHeader2" class="catselect" href="#r">Horror</a>

  </div>
  <div class="select"> <a id="myHeader3" class="catselect" href="#">Action</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

***Updated upon a comment:***

If you check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y0rk8fcd/1/), while what you asked for could be done with pure css but it wouldn't give the perfect effect, with several liens of javascript, initially all  `.data-div` are out of the view window, as the user clicks one of the links, all of these `div`'s - *if any in the view* - slide out the view as we add a transition class `.slide-out` to them, then we pick the `href` value of that specific link the user clicked and use it to address the corresponding `div` and remove the `.slide-out` class from it then add a class `.slide-in` with transition to it to make it slide into the view.

```js
$('.catselect').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    var type = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.data-div').removeClass('slide-in').addClass('slide-out');
 $(type).removeClass('slide-out').addClass('slide-in');
});
```

```css
.menu-icon {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-icon-part-2/128/menu_hamburger-128.png');
    background-size:30px 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
    top:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#holder {
    border-right:10px maroon solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#999;
    position:relative;
    left:-170px;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;
    z-index:10;
    box-shadow:1px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#holder:hover {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s
}
#holder h1 {
    margin-left:10px;
}
#categories {
    font-weight: 800;
    top: .25%;
    left: 2%;
}
#holder .select {
    width:100%;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-size: 175%;
    border-bottom:dotted #888 1px;
}
#holder .select a {
    color:#222;
    left: 3%;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    padding:3px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#holder .select a:hover {
    color:#E0E0E0;
    background-color:maroon;
}
.data-div {
    width:calc(100% - 80px);
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:22px; /* enter this manually because it depends on the #holder menu height */
    left:-100%;
    transition: left 1s ease-in;
    background-color:#EEE;
}
.data-div h2{text-align:center;}
.slide-in{
    left:50px;
    -webkit-transition:left .7s ease-in;
    transition:left .7s ease-in;
}
.slide-out{
    left:-100%;
    -webkit-transition:left .5s ease-out;
    transition:left .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
     <h1 id="categories">Categories<i class="menu-icon"></i></h1>

    <div class="select"> <a class="catselect" href="#comedy">Comedy</a>

    </div>
    <div class="select"> <a class="catselect" href="#horror">Horror</a>

    </div>
    <div class="select"> <a class="catselect" href="#action">Action</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="data-container"></div>
<div id="comedy" class="data-div"><h2>Comedy Data</h2><p>Caffeine irish breve kopi-luwak grounds at pumpkin spice. Cinnamon arabica caffeine a mazagran siphon aroma acerbic. Sit french press seasonal id decaffeinated so trifecta. And doppio decaffeinated, galão cup grounds robusta irish black steamed.
</p><p>
Organic, rich, cup galão black caffeine filter. Aroma, whipped, so con panna organic java mocha. Turkish, cinnamon plunger pot rich pumpkin spice frappuccino caramelization. Spoon bar caramelization coffee iced, robust cup doppio id mug galão.
</p><p>
In acerbic, wings mocha robust qui sugar so as at beans ristretto. Flavour et, est sit frappuccino plunger pot doppio. Body, in saucer plunger pot macchiato lungo frappuccino irish shop. Fair trade, affogato irish coffee to go extraction single origin at dark blue mountain acerbic.</p></div>
<div id="horror" class="data-div"><h2>Horror Data</h2><p>Cortado con panna, as strong, et, grinder milk, caramelization instant flavour galão single shot. Barista bar, strong caramelization cappuccino java robusta foam kopi-luwak. Cream in seasonal, cappuccino, siphon sugar shop qui id crema. Milk, cup sit coffee grounds affogato sweet acerbic.
</p><p>
Mazagran, carajillo grounds java, acerbic, qui aftertaste brewed espresso crema. So frappuccino variety, turkish, beans, mug blue mountain galão strong robusta irish affogato. Skinny irish, french press caramelization qui barista cream. Filter, extra ut cup mug steamed cream that foam.
</p><p>
Mocha, extraction, coffee cream seasonal a shop sweet foam. Carajillo, sit carajillo redeye in extraction, black robust turkish redeye grounds. Cinnamon cream skinny id mocha half and half cappuccino trifecta milk french press arabica. Cinnamon trifecta spoon espresso siphon plunger pot black.
</p><p>
Arabica seasonal medium froth trifecta grinder single origin. And, at, eu, single shot froth cortado, plunger pot so et sugar medium. Sweet blue mountain eu java rich eu instant fair trade redeye. Coffee café au lait single shot, filter acerbic doppio roast dripper turkish shop ristretto skinny.
</p><p>
Lungo grounds, decaffeinated barista brewed bar and robust crema lungo. Mug arabica, viennese café au lait turkish roast sit est plunger pot. Lungo, java decaffeinated sit wings robust cream latte sugar crema strong. Java con panna, mug iced extra dripper single shot kopi-luwak organic.
</p><p>
Milk seasonal frappuccino variety, galão americano, white spoon beans irish coffee. Steamed single origin half and half, blue mountain mug carajillo foam lungo est macchiato. Filter, single shot siphon cup frappuccino lungo grounds. Plunger pot, at americano skinny bar brewed redeye.</p></div>
<div id="action" class="data-div"><h2>Action Data</h2><p>That, skinny, black, strong seasonal ristretto aged lungo. Black, eu robust single origin to go black froth blue mountain cinnamon wings. Dripper fair trade dark barista foam arabica strong. Skinny organic, french press americano, body con panna siphon aroma flavour.
</p><p>
Breve redeye, dark, sugar strong mug doppio plunger pot breve. Shop, turkish strong variety cinnamon mocha at chicory redeye cream strong aroma. Wings macchiato, at coffee acerbic galão seasonal cinnamon variety. Cup caffeine et at brewed con panna mocha et dark.</p></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I Should've been more specific, I want it so when a link is clicked a different div slides to the right of the links.

Comment: and it should slide from the left or the right of the view? also each link will make a unique div slides in or all links will make the same div slides it but with different content?

Comment: It should slide in from the left. And I'd prefer all the links to make the same Div slide in but with different content

Comment: ok I followed whats in the JSFiddle but for some reason the transitions aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `left` property of element with transition.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divClickMe').on("click",function(){
        if(parseInt($('#divSideAd').css('left')) < 0){
            $('#divSideAd').css('left','50px');
            $('#divClickButton').addClass('invisibleField');
        }
        else{
            $('#divSideAd').css('left','-270px');
            $('#divClickButton').removeClass('invisibleField');
        }
    })
})
```

```css
.sideDiv{
    position:absolute;
    left: -270px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 300px;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px cyan;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:1%;
    -webkit-transition:2s;
}

.invisibleField{
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sideDiv" id="divSideAd">
    <table Id="divClickMe">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:90%"><span>Click Me to Hide</span> </td>
            <td style="width:5%"><div id="divClickButton">C L I C K  M E!</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
</div>
```

Hope it helps.